# Flask cross domain not working together with namespace

Tags: python, flask, cors, namespaces, cross-domain

After importing and CORS from flask_cors I get the flask server to support requests from localhost. But only if the request is under the api.route.

For any target under a namespace, I get ***Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5151/api/hello2' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy***

*app.py*

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins":"*"}})
...
...
def initialize_app(flask_app):
"""
Register blueprints and append all namespaces
"""
    blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
    api.init_app(blueprint)
    api.add_namespace(hello_namespace)

    flask_app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
```

*restplus.py*

```
api = Api(version='1.0', title='API', description='API ...')

@api.route('/hello')
class HelloWorld(Resource):            
    def get(self):                     
        return {'hello': 'world from API'}
```

*Namespace.py*

```
ns = api.namespace('hello2', description='Hello endpoints')

@ns.route('/')
@api.doc(responses={404: 'Failed to connect'}, description='List all')
class HelloList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return [{'hello': 'world from API'}]
```

Get data from http://127.0.0.1:5151/api/hello works.
http://127.0.0.1:5151/api/hello2 gives me an error.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

**corydolphin** commented on 18 Mar 2016
https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors/issues/128#issuecomment-198453999

"I expect what is happening is that Flask is silently redirection from 'foo' to 'foo/'. Flask does this automatically."

Sloved by adding the tailing slash to the request on the client side.
http://127.0.0.1:5151/api/hello2/ is now working.